# Power outage solutions required

Tags: power

Is there a nice way to protect your PC from getting damaged (in the sense of both software and hardware) on power outage? Is there a way to protect it other than having a UPS ?

Comment: Why are you ruling out a UPS? A good-quality UPS is *the* solution to the problem you describe.

Comment: Other than a UPS? Unplug it.  I agree with Michael - a UPS is designed for EXACTLY what you're asking for, so please explain to us why a UPS is not a valid solution for you, or risk you question being closed as "unclear", and/or downvoted as "not useful".

Comment: Use a laptop.  The power adapter and battery provide you with protections equivalent to a surge protector and UPS.

Answer (score 2):

To protect the hardware, you must use mains sockets with surge protection for all computing equipment: PCs, printers, router, network discs etc. Some of these have an additional filter to protect your broadband feed, and you should connect your router through this.

After the hardware, the main problem is disc corruption, caused by unwritten buffered writes. Depending on your OS, there may be software available that runs periodically to ensure that all write data are posted. You can also turn off disc write-caching, but there is a high performance penalty, and disc drives themselves may have internal buffers which you cannot control. These measures reduce the chance of corruption, but cannot eliminate it.

Even if all the write data are posted to disc, many databases require a succession of writes to complete in order to maintain integrity, and an interruption to this sequence will corrupt the database.

All of which means that for complete security you need a UPS. You can get some low-capacity models which give a limited time, not enough to maintain the system during a power cut, but long enough to allow the system to hibernate, which will allow it to continue without corruption when power is restored. Some communication errors may be generated on restoration if the system hibernates between a request and a response, but the requesting application should be able to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

@AFH is largely correct in the approach he is taking, although I disagree with his conclusion - and indeed the conclusions of most posters that you "need a UPS" to do this - I can think of plenty of scenarios where a surge protector is adequate.

There are, as you posited 2 different parts to the problem -  The first, and easier to answer - is hardware damage. In order to protect your hardware from damage you need some kind of a filter.  A surge protector or "zap catcher" will probably be adequate - but if you were being paranoid (and its overkill for most scenarios - particularly if you are trying to save money), you could always do some kind of AC -> DC -> AC conversion, making sure your output is a sinusoid wave.  Note that some providers of surge protectors guarantee equipment behind the surge protector if you are trying to protect against a financial risk.

The harder part is the software -

The problem, as @AFH suggested - is a badly timed interrupted write.  There are multiple ways you can mitigate/resolve this issue, including turning off write caching, [using a journalling file system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12699/do-journaling-filesystems-guarantee-against-corruption-after-a-power-failure), getting a battery backed write cache.

Of-course, you can simply bypass the problem depending on your scenario by having a "read only" boot image or network based which mounts, if required, a read/write filesystem over a network (Internet ?) which, effectively, outsources the disk protection issues to someone else - which means YOU don't need a UPS, but the remote disk provider certainly does.  Because of the significant IO penalties and possible network costs, this may not be viable depending on the amount of disk activity.

Comment: The main problem with the surge protector solution is that most of the inexpensive ones are based on simple, cheap MOV circuits, which get destroyed in the process of saving the equipment from surges.